# Karma/Jasmine unit test for D3 svg element

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am working on an Angular app and I am using Jasmine to write the unit tests and Karma as test runner.

We are using `D3` for visualization.

My actual code is something like this.

```
createPlot(ds, "#firstDiv", "constant1", "constant2", "constant3", 1300, 500);
```

where `ds` is my data and `"#firstDiv"` is the id of the DIV where I need SVG.

Inside createPlot, I have something like

```
var svg = d3.select(divId).append("svg")
        .attr("width", someValue)
        .attr("height", someValue);
```

I need to call createPlot function with various div ids on my page.

This code actually works and creates SVGs as needed.

My question is:

I would like to write jasmine unit test for this using Karma test runner.

How can test that after calling "createPlot" "svg" has been created?

Any example or help is greatly appreciated.

Update:  (tried Dayan's suggestion with below code, but it didn't work)

```
describe('D3 Page', function () {
    var ctrl, scope, element, compile;
    var html ='<div id="first"> </div>';
    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $injector, $compile) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('D3PageCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
        compile = $compile;
        element = compile(angular.element(html))(scope);
    }));
    afterEach(function() {       
    });
    it('should create svg', function(){
        createPlot(ds, "#first",  "constant1", "constant1", "operatorsNOp", 1300, 500);
        console.log(element.html()); // prints ' '
        element = compile( angular.element(html) )( scope );
        element.scope().$digest();
        console.log(element.html()); // prints ' '
        console.log(element.find('svg').length); // prints 0
        expect(element.find('svg').length).toBe(1);  // fails
    });
});
```

Comment: you can create a div element w/o attache it to the DOM and pass it to your function and once its done, you should be able to traverse the element and see its children, you can execute queries in it as if it where attached using JQuery , d3 or  vanilla javascript using getElement[s]By[ID,TagName|...

Comment: Can you show me an example of code? I am new to jasmine and d3....if you can post some code, it will be great help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should serve as a guide:

```
describe('sample tests', function () {
    var container;
    beforeEach(function () {
       container = document.createElement('div');
       createPlot(container, "#firstDiv", "constant1", "constant2", "constant3", 1300, 500);
    })

    afterEach(function () {
       container=null;
    })

    it('should have svg', function () {
         var svg = container.getElementsByTagName('svg');
         expect(svg).not.toBe(null);
    })
})
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (updated my question with the code I tried). It didn't work. Not sure if I am doing anything wrong. Can you help?

Comment: what errors do you see in the console? or in the report?

Comment: I don't see any error messages except that test fails with the message "Expected 0 to be 1".

Comment: can you do a console log of your div and see the children elements?

Comment: You have a typo - "document.createlEment" should be "document.createElement"